# playframework-1.x heroku postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku, playframework-1.x

I just tried to deployed a play 1.2.4 app to heroku.
The App works great locally, but on heroku i just got some strange errors, as soon as i try to save some data.

```
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]: Internal Server Error (500) for request POST /players/save
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]: Oops: UnexpectedException
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]: An unexpected error occured caused by exception UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.data.validation.ValidationPlugin.beforeActionInvocation(ValidationPlugin.java:59)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.plugins.PluginCollection.beforeActionInvocation(PluginCollection.java:594)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:134)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.bind(JPAPlugin.java:84)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.plugins.PluginCollection.bind(PluginCollection.java:534)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.data.binding.Binder.bind(Binder.java:111)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.getActionMethodArgs(ActionInvoker.java:642)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.data.validation.ValidationPlugin$Validator.validateAction(ValidationPlugin.java:96)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.data.validation.ValidationPlugin.beforeActionInvocation(ValidationPlugin.java:51)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   ... 3 more
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:307)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.bind(JPAPlugin.java:79)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   ... 8 more
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:274)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   ... 9 more
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = bytea
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   Position: 130
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
2012-07-02T21:26:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   ... 17 more
```

The App is public accessable here:
https://github.com/phaus/kickster

I also tried to use db evolutions first. It did not work neither.
I found several pages for

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = bytea

but i looks, like the problem is within the Play Framework?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Play Framework bug that has been fixed in Play 1.2.5.

Comment: i used: 

> heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev

to activate the new dev DB, but the error is still the same.

Comment: Did you remove the `shared-database` add-on and promote the dev DB to `DATABASE_URL`?

Comment: i promoted the url from the database from https://postgres.heroku.com/databases - still the same error. The funny thing is, that the Play! Template from the heroku dev blog works just fine. I double-checked the setting from the application.conf, it looks the same. So maybe there are some problem with more complex models? I will test agains a local postsql setup this weekend.

Comment: Ok.  Double check with `heroku config` that the `DATABASE_URL` is set to the new Postgres URL.

Comment: Still the same error. Heroku config gives me

imotep:kickster philipp$ heroku config
=== Config Vars for simple-cloud-8060
DATABASE_URL:               postgres://XXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXX@ec2-23-23-234-207.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/ddej30ahhs8qab
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK_URL: postgres://XXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXX@ec2-23-23-234-207.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/ddej30ahhs8qab
JAVA_OPTS:                  -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops
PATH:                       .play:.tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
PLAY_OPTS:                --%prod -Dprecompiled=true

Comment: I've cleaned up a few things in the git repo for the app and now it runs on Heroku without any errors.  Here are my changes: https://github.com/jamesward/kickster  Let me know if you want me to send you a pull request.

Comment: great. of course i would like to have the updates. Ah i see... maybe the tmp file was the problem? Anyway greate that the stuff works right now!

Comment: thank you for the pull request. This thing still does not work. I also tried to deploy your version: https://gist.github.com/3078819 these are the steps i performed. I am sure i miss something. I don't know what :-/.

Comment: Ah.  Looks like I wasn't reproducing the error since it doesn't happen until a new player is created.  Looking into it.

Comment: This may be a bug in Play: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/_tGAMG2CBt0/discussion  I'm trying Play 1.2.5 to see if that fixes it.

Comment: hey... cool... that fixed the deployment \o/. Thank you for your help!